# Changing from Sqllite to Postgres on Heroku- why it is not working?

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I am a bit confused , hope someone can help me out

Originally I uploaded my django  app to heroku account with sqllite db

This is what I had in my settings file for DB

```
 DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
          'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
      }  }

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

It didnt work great since SQLlite was getting flashed to its original state every 24 hours (but worked perfectly since I needed demo system)

However now I have to make it productive so I want to change the db to connect to postgres . So I used credentials from postgres DB I created with heroku and my db in settings looks like this

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'd4drq1yytest',
        'USER': 'xvvqgkjtest',
        'PASSWORD': 'test5y55y5y5y5y5y5y5y5y5y54y45',
        'HOST': '777-77-77-67-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}

import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)
```

But even I changed the settings file and redeployed the new file I still see that my heroku app is connected to my sqllite DB.

What did I do wrong? (I deploy using a master brunch from my github.)

Answer (score 1):

If you have not already, you might need to add heroku postgres as an app in your heroku app's dashboard.

It seems like you have used the same code that I used to connect my heroku's postgres to heroku. You should only have to state

`import dj_database_url
db_from_env = dj_database_url.config()
DATABASES['default'].update(db_from_env)`

then make sure you have pip installed whitenoise and added that to requirements.txt. After commmiting, and pushing to heroku, you may want to run `heroku run bash` on cmd or terminal. Then you may want to run `python manage.py makemigrations yourappname` afterwards, you may want to run `python manage.py migrate`, and if you get no errors, you might want to check on your heroku dashboard for your app, clicking on postgres, to see if any of the postgres' tables are in use. If they are, then you are using the heroku postgres.

you may not need the lines of code below for heroku

`DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'd4drq1yytest',
        'USER': 'xvvqgkjtest',
        'PASSWORD': 'test5y55y5y5y5y5y5y5y5y5y54y45',
        'HOST': '777-77-77-67-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}`

this should be where you are calling the database you will be testing with your localhost.